# Problem with ASP.NET MVC DropDownList not displaying selected value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have an aspx page which allows me to edit articles. Among things I can edit is which category the article belongs to. The category is chosen through a DropDownList as shown here,

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("categoryID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CategoryID"], new { @class = "textbox" }) %>
```

However, the articles category isn't selected when I go to that page. The ViewData I use for the DropDownList looks like this,

```
ViewData["CategoryID"] = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryID", "Title", article.CategoryID);
```

Which should select the article.CategoryID as it's selected value.
Have I done this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the `ViewData` property a `SelectList`, but casting it to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - try typing directly to `SelectList` instead:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("categoryId", (SelectList)ViewData["CategoryID"], new { @class = "textbox" }) %>
```

Comment: No, this made no difference. When going to editArticle.aspx the dropdownlist is still not displaying the correct category for the article.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could suggest is that you ensure your "Category" class has a property called "CategoryID" and is not just "ID". From what you've given us that's the best guess I can make as to the problem.

If it is just "ID", then your function will need to go:

```
ViewData["CategoryID"] = new SelectList(categories, "ID", "Title", article.CategoryID);
```